# Why won't my keystroke in AppleScript command turn an open email message into an "outgoing" message?

Tags: macos, email, applescript

I am trying to implement an AppleScript to find emails in a mailbox that are saved drafts of outgoing emails. Each one found there should then be opened, , turned into an outgoing message and then sent. I have gotten really close, but in the following script The keystroke command does nothing. It should turn the message into an outgoing message by invoking "Send Again".

```
using terms from application "Mail"
    tell application "Mail"
        set theMailbox to mailbox "OutgoingEmail" of account "iCloud"
        set foundMsgs to (every message in theMailbox)
        set the messageCount to the count of foundMsgs
        repeat with i from 1 to the messageCount
            set newMsg to item i of foundMsgs
            tell newMsg
                open
                tell application "System Events"
                    tell application process "Mail"
                        keystroke "D" using {shift down, command down}
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end repeat
    end tell
end using terms from
```

It does nothing though. The message is opened, but the keystroke has no effect. The next step would be to send the message, but that is not shown in the script.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to be using the "using terms from Mail" command, since you then have a tell block for mail on the very next line.

Try this code and see if it works.

```
    tell application "Mail"
        set theMailbox to mailbox "OutgoingEmail" of account "iCloud"
        set foundMsgs to (every message in theMailbox)
        set the messageCount to the count of foundMsgs
        repeat with i from 1 to the messageCount
            set newMsg to item i of foundMsgs
            tell newMsg
                open

            end tell
tell application "System Events"
                    tell application process "Mail"
                        keystroke "D" using {shift down, command down}
                    end tell
                end tell
        end repeat
    end tell
```

Also try a seperate script of just the system events commands to see if they work on their own...

```
tell application "System Events"
                    tell application process "Mail"
                        keystroke "D" using {shift down, command down}
                    end tell
                end tell
```